# Placing NaNs where difference between rows is greater than certain amount

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fix a time series dataset of directional values (0-360 degrees) where points jump a certain amount and cause vertical lines in my plot. To solve this I would like to place NaNs in these spots so they don't plot. The dataframe contains stations and the variables for a certain time span. Looks something like this:

```
In [1]: windData
Out[1]: 
                          Stat1       Stat2  ...      Stat71      Stat72
0                                            ...                        
2018-09-09 06:00:00  137.733582  179.545227  ...    4.856323    4.842651
2018-09-09 06:10:00  137.886902  180.022339  ...   10.627319    9.420166
2018-09-09 06:20:00  138.012634  180.438965  ...   25.765625   24.234741
2018-09-09 06:30:00  138.112305  180.758179  ...   32.981506   31.843384
2018-09-09 06:40:00  138.188080  180.958557  ...   36.052368   35.299866
                        ...         ...  ...         ...         ...
2018-09-26 02:10:00   86.973267   85.516541  ...  142.261230  142.418396
2018-09-26 02:20:00   87.188538   85.504944  ...  142.298218  342.455444
2018-09-26 02:30:00   87.430664   85.490173  ...  142.367004  342.524658
2018-09-26 02:40:00   87.697632   85.472290  ...  142.469055  342.628265
2018-09-26 02:50:00   87.988037   85.451538  ...  142.606628  342.768311

[2430 rows x 72 columns]
```

I would like to place NaNs where the difference between a given time step and the next time step is greater than 180. There are a few ways I have tried doing it, one is doing it on the entire dataframe and then the second way is on a selection based on the station I wish to plot. I am not sure which is more efficient because I will ultimately be looping through all of the stations and making plots of each.

Either way, what I have tried is using `df.diff()` to get the differences and then I used `df.mask(180 < df)` to place NaNs where I want them, but then I am unsure of how to proceed from there and translate all the NaNs in the 'new' dataset into the 'original' where the actual values are. Here is my code for doing it using an individual station:

```
In [1]: df = windData[:][StationNum]

In [2]: df.head(12)
Out[2]: 
0
2018-09-09 06:00:00    143.0
2018-09-09 06:10:00    141.0
2018-09-09 06:20:00    132.0
2018-09-09 06:30:00    147.0
2018-09-09 06:40:00    127.0
2018-09-09 06:50:00    139.0
2018-09-09 07:00:00    146.0
2018-09-09 07:10:00    118.0
2018-09-09 07:20:00    167.0
2018-09-09 07:30:00     50.0
2018-09-09 07:40:00    360.0
2018-09-09 07:50:00     52.0
Name: 41002, dtype: float64

In [3]: dfDif = abs(df.diff())

In [4]:dfDif.head(12)
Out[4]: 
0
2018-09-09 06:00:00      NaN
2018-09-09 06:10:00      2.0
2018-09-09 06:20:00      9.0
2018-09-09 06:30:00     15.0
2018-09-09 06:40:00     20.0
2018-09-09 06:50:00     12.0
2018-09-09 07:00:00      7.0
2018-09-09 07:10:00     28.0
2018-09-09 07:20:00     49.0
2018-09-09 07:30:00    117.0
2018-09-09 07:40:00    310.0
2018-09-09 07:50:00    308.0
Name: 41002, dtype: float64

In [5]: dfMask = dfDif.mask(180 < dfDif)

In [6]: dfMask.head(12)
Out[6]:
0
2018-09-09 06:00:00      NaN
2018-09-09 06:10:00      2.0
2018-09-09 06:20:00      9.0
2018-09-09 06:30:00     15.0
2018-09-09 06:40:00     20.0
2018-09-09 06:50:00     12.0
2018-09-09 07:00:00      7.0
2018-09-09 07:10:00     28.0
2018-09-09 07:20:00     49.0
2018-09-09 07:30:00    117.0
2018-09-09 07:40:00      NaN
2018-09-09 07:50:00      NaN
Name: 41002, dtype: float64
```

I would then like to put these NaNs into the original dataframe df, but I am unsure how to do this. I have tried placing each series (df and dfMask) in the same dataframe and trying to compare and replace, but I begin getting warning messages trying to set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame that I would like to avoid. I save them as their own variables, but maybe I am doing it incorrectly and need to use pd.DataFrame when I create my selection? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you given that, index is same between windData and dfMask, and you set the right column name on dfMask

```
dfMask.columns = ['Stat1'] # set this to what column you want these values to be updated to
windData.update(dfMask)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing. I created a new dataFrame for my given station and then looped through each value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(WindData[:]['StationNum'])
for k in range(0,len(df)-1):
    if abs(df['41002'][k] - df['41002'][k+1]) >= 180:
        df['41002'][k] = np.nan
```